# Terms and condition should be checked before registration

Tags: magento2, registration

I have added a custom checkbox for terms and condition in registration box. I need it to be checked compulsory before registration. Below is my code.

```
<div style="width: auto; margin: 0;" class="field choice custom-terms required">
        <input type="checkbox" data-validate="{'required':true}" value="1" id="termscheck" name="custom-terms" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Terms & conditions') ?>" id="register-input-custom" class="input-checkbox checkbox required-entry" />

        <label for="custom-terms" class="label">
            <span>
                <?php echo __('I have read and accept the ') ?><a href="https://goodwayorganic.com/new/term-and-conditions" target="_blank"><?php echo __('Terms & conditions') ?></a><?php echo __(' and ') ?><a href="https://goodwayorganic.com/new/privacy-policy" target="_blank"><?php echo __('Privacy & policy') ?></a>
            </s`enter code here`pan>
        </label>
    </div>
```

data-validate="{'required':true}" is not working.

For me before saving the terms and condition should be checked.

I am updating my complete form below

```
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' >
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
<fieldset class="fieldset create info">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Personal Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
    <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
        <div class="field choice newsletter">
            <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
            <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
        </div>
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
    <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
    <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</fieldset>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset address">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />

        <?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company') ?>
        <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getFormData()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone') ?>
        <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getFormData()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax') ?>
        <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getFormData()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

        <div class="field street required">
            <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="street[]" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':10,'maxlength':100}" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address')) ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                <div class="nested">
                    <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                    <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <div class="field additional">
                            <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':10,'maxlength':100}" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field country required">
            <label for="country" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Country')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required">
            <label for="city" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="city" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':3}" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>" id="city">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field region required">
            <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('State/Province')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                    <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field zip required">
            <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':10}" name="postcode" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
        <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
            <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
            <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
            <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
            <?= $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
    </fieldset>

<?php endif; ?>
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign-in Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <div class="field required">
        <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{'required':true, 'minlength':6, 'maxlength':50, 'validate-email':true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field password required">
        <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                   class="input-text"
                   data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                   data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                   data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                   autocomplete="off">
            <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                    <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="field confirmation required">
        <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--------termsandcondition--->
    <div style="width: auto; margin: 0;" class="field choice custom-terms required">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check" name="check" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Terms & conditions') ?>" id="register-input-custom" class="input-checkbox checkbox required-entry" />


        <label for="custom-terms" class="label">
            <span>
                <?php echo __('I have read and accept the ') ?><a href="https://goodwayorganic.com/new/term-and-conditions" target="_blank"><?php echo __('Terms & conditions') ?></a><?php echo __(' and ') ?><a href="https://goodwayorganic.com/new/privacy-policy" target="_blank"><?php echo __('Privacy & policy') ?></a>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>

<!--------------->

    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Create an Account')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add class required-entry only. don't add  data-validate="{'required':true}"

Comment: Added the class required-entry and removed data-validate="{'required':true}"  but still validation is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` in your form

```
<form id="custom-form" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <input class="input required-entry" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" />  I agree to the Terms and Conditions.
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
```

Or

```
<form id="custom-form">
    <input class="input required-entry" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-one-required-by-name':true}" />  I agree to the Terms and Conditions.
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### **Update :**

I tested your code and it works

[image]

Comment: I tried both but still not working...…..

Comment: Is there any way I can validate through .xml file for registration form because I was facing the same problem in shipping address but after validation through .xml it worked for me for shipping address

Comment: My solution works, I confirm check again your code

Comment: I have added my complete form in the question please do check once

Comment: Look my update...

Comment: Its not working for me.... am I missing any thing other than the form.?

Comment: Look if you have some js errors

Comment: yes I was having errors in js. Rectified it and its working fine.

Comment: Cool, thanks to accept the answer if it helped you